# How to read the output of show operator back to a Dataset?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Assuming we have the following text file (output of `df.show()` command):

```
+----+---------+--------+
|col1|     col2|    col3|
+----+---------+--------+
|   1|pi number|3.141592|
|   2| e number| 2.71828|
+----+---------+--------+
```

Now i want to read/parse it as a DataFrame/Dataset. What is the most "sparkling" way to do this?

p.s. I'm interested in solutions for **both** `scala` and `pyspark`, that's why  both tags are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** using "UNIVOCITY" parser lib i could get rid of one line where i was removing whitespaces in the column names:

Scala:

```
// read Spark Output Fixed width table:
def readSparkOutput(filePath: String) : org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = {
    val t = spark.read
                 .option("header","true")
                 .option("inferSchema","true")
                 .option("delimiter","|")
                 .option("parserLib","UNIVOCITY")
                 .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","true")
                 .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","true")
                 .option("comment","+")
                 .csv(filePath)
    t.select(t.columns.filterNot(_.startsWith("_c")).map(t(_)):_*)
}
```

PySpark:

```
def read_spark_output(file_path):
    t = spark.read \
             .option("header","true") \
             .option("inferSchema","true") \
             .option("delimiter","|") \
             .option("parserLib","UNIVOCITY") \
             .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","true") \
             .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","true") \
             .option("comment","+") \
             .csv("file:///tmp/spark.out")
    # select not-null columns
    return t.select([c for c in t.columns if not c.startswith("_")])
```

---

Usage example:

```
scala> val df = readSparkOutput("file:///tmp/spark.out")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df.show
+----+---------+--------+
|col1|     col2|    col3|
+----+---------+--------+
|   1|pi number|3.141592|
|   2| e number| 2.71828|
+----+---------+--------+


scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- col1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: double (nullable = true)
```

---

**Old answer:**

Here is my attempt in scala (Spark 2.2):

```
// read Spark Output Fixed width table:
val t = spark.read
    .option("header","true")
    .option("inferSchema","true")
    .option("delimiter","|")
    .option("comment","+")
    .csv("file:///temp/spark.out")
// select not-null columns
val cols = t.columns.filterNot(c => c.startsWith("_c")).map(a => t(a))
// trim spaces from columns
val colsTrimmed = t.columns.filterNot(c => c.startsWith("_c")).map(c => c.replaceAll("\\s+",""))
// reanme columns using 'colsTrimmed'
val df = t.select(cols:_*).toDF(colsTrimmed:_*)
```

It works, but i have a feeling that there must be much more elegant way to do this.

```
scala> df.show
+----+---------+--------+
|col1|     col2|    col3|
+----+---------+--------+
| 1.0|pi number|3.141592|
| 2.0| e number| 2.71828|
+----+---------+--------+

scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- col1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I've always been thinking about writing a custom Spark source, but your solution is simply clever! Thanks.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski, no, thank you!!! I'm learning a LOT from your [Mastering Apache Spark 2](https://www.gitbook.com/book/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark/details) and from your answers.

Comment: @MaxU, can you please have look at my question ` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509187/pandas-create-dataframe-with-index-name-as-column-name/50509256?noredirect=1#comment88032615_50509256 `