# Pandas create Dataframe with index name as column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have an existing dataframe with column name and data. I want to change `index.name` for dataframe to be column's name. I am confused about `multi - indexing` how do I do that? Because then I need to pass that dataframe to the `to_sql` function which considers index as name of column for table.

Currently for me `dataframe.index` is `RangeIndex(start=0, stop=1669, step=1)`

and `dataframe.index.name` is `None`

I have done as follows :

```
dataframe.index.names = dataframe.columns
dataframe = dataframe.rename_axis(dataframe.columns)
```

It's giving me error as `Length of new names must be 1, got 67`. 67 is number of column I have in dataframe.

Comment: for `df.index` it's printing `0...500` which is number of rows . I want indexing should be on column name and for all column.

Comment: Can you add some sample?

Comment: Why downwote guys?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if `MultiIndex` or not.

For single index need:

```
df.index.name = 'foo'
df = df.rename_axis('foo')
```

For `MultiIndex` need:

```
df.index.names = ('foo', 'bar')
df = df.rename_axis(('foo', 'bar'))
```

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - Why need this? Because `name` is scalar and want add many columns names, it does not work.

Comment: Doing all this for ` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50503934/pandas-to-sql-error-invalid-column-name-none?noredirect=1#comment88024385_50503934 `

Comment: hmmm, hard to know without data, but one idea - is some columns name `NaN` ? Is possible check it? `print (pd.isnull(df.columns).sum())` ?

Comment: Yup there are some column as `NaN`

Comment: So there is problem, need change them. There is multiple `NaN`s columns?

Comment: Discussing for that question? yes there are multiple column as `NaN`, How do I change them to something so that it will show `NA` field in database.

Comment: What return `print (pd.isnull(df.columns).sum())` ?

Comment: It's giving `0`.

Comment: `print (df.columns.duplicated().sum())` There are some duplicated columns names?

Comment: It's giving `0` for this also.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - So it is bad :( No idea, sorry. Maybe try ask MaxU, he is db expert. Try add some cooment under his question.

Comment: Actually when I have created table by giving new table name it has created table and added data for that, even it is accepting this file everytime, but same table created by my manager for that it is giving me error.

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare - hmmm, hard question, if sometimes working sometimes not. It is obviously hard find difference between working and not what generate error :(:(:(

Comment: yup very hard .